# Counter Example for Limit integral interchanging

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist an increasing series of riemann integrable functions $\{f_n\}$ such that they converge to a riemann integrable function $f$. But do not satisfy the property $Lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int f_n \neq\int f$. From the theorem proved in class I understood that uniform continuity is needed,but how much ever I try I am unable to come up with such an example.

I tried $z^n$ in the interval $(0,1)$ . It goes to zero but integrals limit also goes to zero.So i am guessing there does not exist such functions.So if anyone can provide an example of above type of functions it would be of great help.Thanks

Comment: @DavidMitra It is not an increasing sequence of functions ie $f_3(0.5)=0$ but $f_1(0.5)=1$

Comment: The Monotone Convergence Theorem says no. An elementary argument, in the setting of the Riemann integral, can be found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.sfu.ca%2Fhome%2Fthomson%40sfu.ca%2FMyRecentPapers%2Fmonthly547-550-thomson.pdf&ei=L_gNU9CtB8KosAT7oYCoBg&usg=AFQjCNHfZydWNfA7FdtA6mbfb1aXPI1k7A&bvm=bv.61965928,d.cWc).

Comment: See the dominated convergence theorem, it may help you understand when you can interchange a limit and an integral.

Comment: @DavidMitra can you please summarise the proof the link does not seem to be working

Comment: Try the links from the author's blog [here](http://classicalrealanalysis.blogspot.com/2010/02/riemann-integral-indeed.html).